# Is that okay that android does open links from sms automatically (google does scanning my sms)?

Tags: android, sms

I have android 10 huawei phone.
I found out that when I receive an sms with a link in it, my phone does a background request to the linked url.
For the test, I've made a custom link to my apache server. And checked the logs. I can see a regular GET request coming from non-my IP (66.102.9.127 which seems to be a google-related IP).

I know about the OG. But my settings state that I should explicitly click the preview area to load the OG.

That looks like a security breach, as some services may send my one-time verification links. And it seems, like google does some scanning on my messages and checks the links in it.

Answer (score 0):

You might wanna check any base application comes with the phone doing that or not, instead of google. Any trace logs?

Comment: As far as I know in last androids only one app may have access to sms. Other apps don't have a persmission to access sms. And, by the way, I am using google messaging app for sms as my default sms viewer app.

Comment: Since, u said the google messaging app as default. Then its might be the behavior of the app, unless u change to different app.